# UITouch UIWebview make active if disabled

Tags: iphone, uiview, ipad

I have 4 UIviews (not overlapping), one active, and 3 not enabled. I want to set one of the 3 non-enabled views to active by a touch, I thought touchesBegan: but it doesn't work. any ideas? will this work with uiwebviews as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by active, but you should have no problem using touchesBegan to enable one UIView and disable another. Could you post some code?

Comment: is it possible to use a UIWebView instead of a UIView. I want to set a uiWebview from .enabled = NO; to .enabled = YES on a touch if not enabled. I have also read that I can overlay a UIView on top of the UIWebView and use that to toggle. Thanks.

Comment: I don't use UIWebViews so I don't know how they differ in the enabled/disabled states, but UIWebView is a subclass of UIView so you should be able to enable/disable it without a problem.